How to efficiently set a property to 0 for an entire array in c++
I have a structure "Struct" with a field "foo" and a very large static "Struct" array.
What is the most efficient way of setting the field "foo" to 0 for the entire array?
Note that I don't care about the state of the other fields after this operation. If they get cleared, that's fine.
What I tried:
for(Struct& s : array) {
    s.foo = 0;
}

and
memset(array, 0, ARRAY_SIZE);

Are there more efficient methods?
Does the position of the count field in the layout of "Struct" matter?

std::array<int,128> s{}; or  struct s { int x; std::array<int,128> arrl }; s{};

You overthink this. When optimizations are enabled compiler is smart enough to generate exactly same code for all versions you have provided. Looks like you are beginner so learn first to write correct and readable code, then when you learn that start warring about performance by thinking about algorithm complexity.

memset will mess up objects of polymorphic type, but that also makes it likely the most performant. A type safe variant may be std::ranges::fill(array, {});

std::fill would be the usual C++ solution (IMHO).

@MarekR I am very new to c++ indeed. Could you clarify what wasn't legible in my code? The loop variable being called "s"? I take your point about compilers, given my level of c++ I hoped that there was something I was missing but I'll probably just stick with memset. It just seems like "overkill" since I don't need to set ALL fields to 0. Hoped for a silver bullet that just set that one field at the start of the struct.

array = {}; as mentioned in the first comment is a simple solution. I suppose Marek calls your approaches "overkill" because you are using a complicated powerful tool (memset) to do something that can be done in a much simpler fashion. "overthinking" because, as they tried to explain, no difference in performance is to be expected for different variants of code when they have the same effective observable behavior.

@EmerickGibson do not mix c-code into C++ if this is not needed. Make code clear to reader and let compiler do its magic. From C++ point of view memset(array, 0, ARRAY_SIZE); looks suspicious and dangerous (bug-prone) and basically it is obsolete over-engineering. And depending on Struct content it can be even undefined behavior.

When writing normal C++ code, the performance question should be left for the compiler: the programmer should only care for algorithms if it is relevant. Here any simple and readable way should be fine. You should only care whether memset should be used if profiling a program compiled with full optimizations enabled show that you have a bottleneck in the code setting that specific array values, or if you intend to deliver a professional grade library for general usage.

@MarekR Ah ok, got it. Thanks for the clarification!

A short tale about premature optimization.  A coworker rewrote a tricky part of the code with a lot of gnarly (nigh unmaintainable) hand-tweaked code.  He was proud that it was x3 faster!  I tested it, it was x100 slower.  Hmmm.  After a bit of puzzlement, we realized that he was testing with -O0, and I was testing with -O2.  The end.

When performance is an issue, you might choose a "struct of arrays" over an "array of structs". That is to say, you'd access a.b[i] instead of a[i].b. This works in most compiled languages. C++ specific, you can do this with both std::array and std::vector.

@Eljay Welcome to approximately 100% of all performance-related questions on SO. Here people absolutely love to benchmark their code with optimizations disabled...

@Eljay -- The coworker didn't realize that overly-complex code will many times make the compiler's optimizer give up.  That's why it was 100x slower.  A lot of programmers believe we are back in the 1980's C programming, where doing tricks with pointers would speed up the code, but those were the days when compiler optimization techniques were not as robust as they are now.

on top of what has been said already a lot of code doesn't need to be blazing fast but any code needs to be written, read, and maintained. It depends on the details of what you do, in my case roughly 90% of my code can be as slow as it wants, because it doesn't do anything urgent. And for the other 10% where speed matters, correctness and thus simplicity and readability matters so much more.

@PaulMcKenzie • in this case it was x100 slower because the DEC Alpha does not support byte access to memory, it only supports word access.  Misaligned word access would fault, and the OS would do the reading of the two words, shifting and masking, and return control to the application with the asked for misaligned word in the register.  (A program could also be compiled just to segfault and terminate, rather than have the OS do the expensive heavy lifting.) His hand-tweaked code relied on all misaligned access and slow byte reading/writing.

Don't try mem functions ever. Primary reason is that if your objects are not trivial, all kinds of UB and bugs appear. Provide constructors, default values for member, try std::ranges::fill on containers, or a range-based loop as last resort. Using mem functions has certain preconditions and only seldom helpful, in case of a defect or missed optimization in std implementation.

Like usual, I would quote a classic:

The first rule of optimization is: Don’t do it.
The second rule of optimization (for experts only) is: Don’t do it yet

So, before writing something non-intuitive, like std::memset instead of foo = 0, at least try to benchmark your code and see if there is any significant difference. Assuming that your struct is something around
constexpr size_t PAD_SIZE = 4;
struct S {
  char dummy[PAD_SIZE];
  int foo;
  char dummy2[PAD_SIZE];
};

I wrote a simple benchmark:
constexpr size_t NUM_ELEM = 10000;

static void ClassicLoop(benchmark::State& state) {
  std::array<S, NUM_ELEM> testArr;
  for (auto _ : state) {
    for(auto& s : testArr) {
        s.foo = 0;
    }
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(testArr);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(ClassicLoop);

static void WithMemset(benchmark::State& state) {
  std::array<S, NUM_ELEM> testArr;
  for (auto _ : state) {
    std::memset(testArr.data(), 0, NUM_ELEM*sizeof(S));
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(testArr);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(WithMemset);

Which one is faster? Depends ... On my PC, if your struct is "small", then WithMemset is on average ~2% faster. If the struct is "big" (let's say PAD_SIZE=64;, then memset version can be twice as slow.
So, write idiomatic code from the beginning, and then only when you identify the bottleneck, try to optimize.

Thank you for going through the trouble of benchmarking the two options and for sharing this benchmarking tool! I'll keep the quote in mind :).

The short answer is that I'd usually use the first loop rather than memset. It should never be slower, and it might be faster.
The longer answer mostly deals with caching. Caches work in "lines". A line is a fixed-size chunk of data (e.g., 64 bytes on most modern Intel processors). As you're zeroing foo, the CPU will read in a cache line, write to what it needs to in that cache line, then write the whole cache line back out to main memory. In your case (doing that a lot) speed is quickly limited by the speed at which the CPU can read and write cache lines, so the amount you write inside of a cache line won't usually matter much.
If each struct is small enough to fit entirely in a single cache line, then you're going to be writing to every cache line. It doesn't matter much whether you overwrite the entire struct or just foo.
But if each struct is large enough that it occupies more than one cache line (and foo fits in only one of those), then writing only to foo will avoid loading the cache lines for the rest of each struct. E.g., if one struct is 256 bytes, we can expect the memset to be about 4x slower than writing only to foo.
CPUs also try to predict what memory you're doing to need next. So using memory in predictable patterns can gain quite a bit of speed. You're walking through the array from beginning to end, which is about as predictable as it gets. So you're already "optimizing" in this respect.
If, however, your foos formed a linked list, and you only needed to zero the first 90% of them, when you traversed the list in order, chances are that it would be faster to zero all of them than to walk through them in an unpredictable order to avoid zeroing a few. For the latter case to work out, you'd need to be able to avoid zeroing a pretty substantial percentage of them (like at least half), not just 10%.
Putting foo first in the struct can help speed a tiny bit. But the difference is tiny even at best. Reading/writing main memory will usually be the bottleneck unless the array is really tiny.

Thanks for the explanation. The structure is 56 bytes long so there should be no time saving by only getting the cache line with foo if I understand your explanation correctly. This question was a long shot at trying to improve performance but given your answers and others, I'll have to live with the performance cost or figure out a way to circumvent the need to reset entirely.
